# Azure Functions Kubernetes cannot find local.settings.json

Tags: c#, docker, kubernetes, azure-functions, keda

I am trying to publish my Azure Functions App to Kubernetes but I am getting the following error when I run this command

`func kubernetes deploy --name my-function-api --namespace default --registry mycontainerregistry/docker-azure-function --csharp`

> Unable to find project root. Expecting to find one of host.json, local.settings.json in project root.`

This is my docker file

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:3.1 AS installer-env

COPY . .
RUN cd /MyFunctionApp.Api && \
    mkdir -p /home/site/wwwroot && \
    dotnet publish *.csproj --output /home/site/wwwroot

COPY /MyFunctionApp.Api/host.json /home/site/wwwroot
COPY /MyFunctionApp.Api/local.settings.json /home/site/wwwroot

# To enable ssh & remote debugging on app service change the base image to the one below
# FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/dotnet:2.0-appservice 
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/dotnet:3.0
ENV AzureWebJobsScriptRoot=/home/site/wwwroot \
    AzureFunctionsJobHost__Logging__Console__IsEnabled=true

COPY --from=installer-env ["/home/site/wwwroot", "/home/site/wwwroot"]
```

As you can see I have tried adding the following lines

```
COPY /MyFunctionApp.Api/host.json /home/site/wwwroot
COPY /MyFunctionApp.Api/local.settings.json /home/site/wwwroot
```

But that does not seem to help either, so not sure what I need to do to get this working?
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok so figured this out. Azure Functions does not read `local.settings.json` or `settings.json` when running in a container. These keys need to be set as environment variables.

You need to have the `local.settings.json` in the the same folder that you run the `func kubernetes deploy` command from and that will generate a yaml file with the settings that get passed into the container when it is started.

NB: this does not seem to work with setting `CORS` settings. I have a new question for that here [CORS Issue with Azure Functions inside AKS Cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65074215/cors-issue-with-azure-functions-inside-aks-cluster)

Comment: did you find docs for this? Or just trial and error? If docs, it would be good to link them.